# CSS border radius for dotted border

Tags: border, css

[image: is it cooled like this on your screen ?][image: heres the screenshot]I'm using dotted borders with round corners but I'm getting a problem. The corners are in a deeper color than the side borders. I want all to be of the same color.

If you see the output of my code then you could understand the problem. heres my code:

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post">
    <table style="border:1px dotted #0000ff;-moz-border-radius:7px;
        -webkit-border-radius:7px;border-radius:7px;" align="center">
        <caption><b>Admin Login</b></caption>
        <tr>
            <td>Username : </td>
            <td><input name="username" id="username" type="text" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>Password : </td>
            <td><input name="password" id="password" type="password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Log in" /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
```

Please tell me how can I fix it.

Thanks.

[ **RESOLVED:** Thank you so much everybody for your kind replies.]

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/Ganec/ looks the same colour to me

Comment: but I see color is deeper in the corners than all other parts of the border. in here color is same when I use 'solid' border, but having problem with dotted border.

Comment: I'm thinking it may be somewhat of an optical illusion

Comment: Nit-pick: Don't use inline styles

Comment: is it cause of inline style ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The solid corners are a limitation of Firefox (and other Gecko-based browsers). [MDN says](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/border-radius):

> Dotted and dashed rounded border corners are rendered as solid in Gecko; see [bug 382721](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721).

Comment: Its a browser bug, yes. Your code is correct, although I'd seriously consider moving all of your CSS to an external file and using the `class` attribute to reference it. Also, `-moz-border-radius` was dropped in Firefox 13, so you might not need it anymore.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help. I usually use external css file but also sometimes use inline css if theres no possibility to use the code again.

Answer (score -1):

Why not something like

```
<form action="checklogin.php" method="post" style="display:block;border:1px dotted #0000ff;-moz-border-radius:7px;-webkit-border-radius:7px;border-radius:10px; width:200px; padding:10px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto;"  >
<h2 style="text-align:center; font-weight:bold">Admin Login</h2>
<labe for="username">Username : </label>
<input name="username" id="username" type="text"/>
<labe for="password">Password : </label>
<input name="password" id="password" type="password" />
<input name="submit" id="submit" type="submit" value="Log in" style="display:block" />
</form>​
```

You will avoid the table and for users it is easier to process labels on top of the inputs not on left. You can check it here [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CvRQJ/)

Comment: see the screenshot of your page. is it looked like that on your screen ?

Comment: This is an improvement in terms of HTML, but it doesn't really answer the question, does it?

Comment: I thought if my code working well on your screen so it could be cause of my screen.