# When i'am trying to give border style dotted in browser it showing solid border below is my css

Tags: html, css, stylesheet

```
.myclass { 
  border: 6px dotted #2d2d2d;
  width:200px;
  height:200px; 
  border-radius:100% 100% 100% 100%; 
}
```

When i'am trying to give full border radius to border: 6px dotted #2d2d2d; in browser it showing solid border not dotted above is my css code please help me.

Comment: [Cannot reproduce](http://jsbin.com/OBEkEHEW/1/edit?html,output). Either your problem is with some other code you are not sharing with us, or it is browser specific, or it has to do with something else not mentioned in the question.

Comment: I can reproduce this in FireFox, but not Chrome.

Comment: What browser are you using?  Working fiddle using your example:  http://jsfiddle.net/h9v9U/

Comment: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

Comment: seems like its aknown bug in firefox https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=382721

Comment: I think you are not sharing other class css related to your post

Comment: What happens if you just use `border-radius:50% 50% 50% 50%;` to make the circle?

Comment: actually i'm looking for dotted circle with css only i hope you understand!!!

Comment: alright guys! actually it's not compatible with mozilla old version back in 2013..! anyway it's working with latest version now. (myClass-Css) :) once again.. thank you all for your replies..!

Answer (score 1):

This only happens in Firefox I think it's a bug - it's because of the radius - you might consider using an image in this case.
[CSS border radius for dotted border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13725351/css-border-radius-for-dotted-border)

Comment: you're right! it's not compatible with mozilla old version back in 2013..! now it's working with latest version.

Answer (score -1):

Instead of writing:

```
border: 6px dotted #2d2d2d;
```

try:

```
border-style: doted;
border-width: 6px;
border-color: #2d2d2d;
```

Thats what I use when I write CSS.

Comment: that is not what i'm looking for actually my problem is that i need dotted border in circle with css. i hope you understand. can you please help me if you have any idea about that!!!